# Oracle Delete Rows Matching On Multiple Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE
student.course, student.major IN
(SELECT schedule.course, schedule.major FROM schedule)
```

However, it seems that you can only use one column with the IN operator. Is that true? Seems like a query like this should be possible.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, you just need parentheses:

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE
(student.course, student.major) IN
(SELECT schedule.course, schedule.major FROM schedule)
```

Comment: So this is actually misleading and I would argue essentially incorrect for how deeply non-intuitive it is.  If your row contains null value IN does not work.  Which, I guess, makes sense for how nulls are, but is completely inconsistent with, for example, how minus works.

Answer (score 17):

You could also use the EXISTS clause:

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE
EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM schedule 
  WHERE schedule.course=student.course 
  AND schedule.major=student.major
)
```

Comment: +1; WHERE EXISTS is a woefully underrated mechanism, much better than use of IN

Comment: @Brian: (I realise I'm a bit late responding to your comment!) Why do you say EXISTS is much better than IN?

Comment: A very good question.  My understanding is that it's a good choice in performance terms, however I've little to offer in terms of evidence.  That said, I've managed to find this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-the-difference-between-in-and-exists-in-subqueries/5297080

Comment: Other, probably more helpful, links: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql

Comment: Well there is also a potential to have too many result values in the IN clause which I have seen cause problems in the past... like more than 1024....

Answer (score 8):

```
DELETE FROM student WHERE
(student.course, student.major) IN
(SELECT schedule.course, schedule.major FROM schedule)
```

Put parens around your terms in the where clause. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Note that if any attributes are null, the row's considered not IN.  That is, if courses are equal and both student and schedule major are null, row will not be deleted.

If an attribute, such as major, may be null, and you want null = null to be true, try:

```
DELETE
FROM student
WHERE (student.course, NVL(student.major,'sOmeStRinG') )
IN (SELECT schedule.course, NVL(schedule.major,'sOmeStRinG') FROM schedule)
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax below works in SQLServer  <strike>but I believe it is a standard sql</strike> 
but as pointed out in comments this is non standard implementation and is not currently supported in Oracle.

I will leave it for reference

```
delete s
from 
    student s 
    inner join schedule sch
    on s.course=sch.course 
    and s.major = sch.major
```

Comment: No, standard SQL supports only one table in DELETE.  MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server support multi-table DELETE as an extension to the standard, but Oracle does not.

Comment: The SQL standard concept of a table isn't strictly limited to a table. It often includes views. Certain views are updatable, and by extension, deletable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it is good to learn about differences in DB implementations. I have updated my answer to include your points

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, you can do a delete from an in-line view, but it generally needs a foreign key that ensures that a row from the table from which the row is deleted cannot be represented by more than one row in the view.

```
create table parent (id number primary key);
create table child (id number primary key, parent_id number references parent);
insert into parent values(1);
insert into child values(2,1);
delete from (select * from parent p, child c where c.parent_id = p.id);
```