# Using rowid to delete duplicate rows from an oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm using the following query to delete duplicate rows from a table. There are only 2 columns in the table (col1 and col2).

```
delete from tab1 where rowid not in
(select min(rowid) from tab1 t group by col1, col2);
```

Is there any problem, like some side effects, if I use this query to delete duplicate rows?

Comment: Using ROWID itself has nothing wrong. That's what Oracle's SQL Developer uses for almost all internal queries.

Comment: I think your present approach based on rowid is right on target. My understanding is that rowid's are one of the _fastest_ ways of accessing data because it is the physical address of that row in the database. Tom Kyte endorses your initial approach [Ask Tom: Deleting Duplicate Records](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1224636375004)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i can tell, your query will perform slow

This should give you a better performance

```
delete t1
from tab1 t1
join tab1 t2
on t1.rowid > t2.rowid 
and t1.col1 = t2.col1 
and t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Or this (it works on mssql, I believe oracle has the same syntax)

```
;WITH [CTE DUPLICATE] AS 
(
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY id) RN
FROM tab1
)
DELETE FROM [CTE DUPLICATE] WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: `This should give you a better performance`, provided you have indexes on the fields `col1` and `col2`

Comment: @Johan even without the index i believe it will give a much better performance

Comment: I see what you mean, with all the `group by` going on in the original query.

Answer (score 0):

This query is ok.  You can phrase it without rownum as described in this question:

[Oracle Delete Rows Matching On Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504060/oracle-delete-rows-matching-on-multiple-values)