# Finding the differences in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two large tables in a database. They both contain a column called "name". My goal is to locate rows that contain names that are in one database but not the other.

I'm guessing there will be a join statement and a where, but I cannot figure out how to use the two in tandem in order to create a successful query.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE NAME NOT IN 
   ( SELECT NAME FROM TABLE_B )
```

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS might be faster than IN, see [Difference between EXISTS and IN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql).

You can use EXISTS like this. It's useful to know both approaches since they are not exactly equal. You can swap the EXISTS quantifier for [SOME, ALL or ANY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME). I think you can figure out what would happen :)

```
select * from a1 where not exists(select 1 from a2 where name=a1.name);
```

Note that they are not 100% equal! SQL has [three-valued logic](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx)!