# how to improve sql when IN is too much

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL that have condition IN is to long. And it take my SQL too much time to execute
is there any way to improve the performance of it?

Here is the SQL

```
SELECT * FROM bi_bunrui_syouhin_shop_day_jyutyuu AS bi   
WHERE bi.bunrui_code IN     
('0001','1000','1001','1005','1006','1007','1008','1009','1010','1011','1012','1013','1014','1015','1016','1017','1018','1020','1021','1022','1023','1030','1031','1032','1033','1034','1036','1037','1038','1039','1040','1041','1043','1044','1045','1046','1050','1054','1055','1060','1061','1070','1080','1081','1082','1083','1084','1085','1086','1088','1090','1091','1092','1093','1094','1095','1096','1097','1100','1101','1102','1103','1104','1105','1106','1107','1108','1109','1110','1111','1112','1113','1114','1115','1116','1117','1118','1119','1120','1121','1122','1123','1130','1131','1132','1133','1134','1135','1136','1137','1140','1141','1142','1143','1145','1148','1150','1151','1152','1153','1154','1155','1156','1157','1160','1161','1162','1163','1164','1165','1166','1167','1168','1169','1170','1171','1180','1181','1182','1183','1184','1187','1189','1200','1201','1202','1203','1204','1205','1206','1207','1210','1211','1212','1220','2003','2009','2022','2028','2042','2048','2062','2068','2082','2088','2102','2108','2122','2125','2128','2129','2134','2141','2144','2161','2182','2186','2222','2228','2242','2253','2262','2268','2302','2511','2512','2513','3180','3207','3208','4023','4024','4028','4029','4030','4031','4032','4033','4034','4036','4040','4041','4042','4043','4044','4062','4064','4066','4067','4068','4069','4070','4071','4092','5013','5014','5015','5016','5017','5018','6200','6201','6202','6203','6204','6205','6220','6221','6222','6223','6224','6225','6226','6234','6235','6240','6241','6242','6243','6244','6245','6246','6247','6249','6250','6251','6260','6261','6262','6263','6264','6265','6280','6281','6282','6283','6284','6285','6286','6287','6288','6289','6290','6291','6292','6293','6300','6301','6302','6303','6304','6305','6320','6321','6322','6323','6324','6325','6340','6342','6343','6344','6345','6346','6347','6348','6349','6360','6361','6362','6363','6364','6365','6366','6367','6368','6369','6371','6372','6373','6374','6375','6376','6377','6378','6379','6380','6381','6382','6383','6384','6385','6400','6401','6402','6403','6406','6407','6408','6420','6421','6422','6423','6424','6425','6426','6427','6428','6429','6430','6431','6432','6433','6434','6435','6436','6440','6441','6442','6443','6444','6445','6446','6447','6448','6449','6450','6451','6452','6453','6454','6455','6456','6457','6458','6459','6460','6470','6471','6472','6473','6474','6475','6476','6477','6478','6480','6481','6482','6483','6484','6485','6486','6487','6489','6490','6500','6501','6502','6504','6505','6506','6507','6508','6509','6510','6511','6512','6513','6514','6515','6520','6521','6522','6523','6524','6525','6526','6527','6528','6529','6530','6531','6550','6551','6552','6553','6554','6555','6556','6557','6558','6559','6560','6561','6562','6563','6564','6565','6567','6568','6569','6570','6572','6573','6574','7694','7993','9200','9201','9202','9203','9204','9205','9206','9208','9310','9320')
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have an index on the bunrui_code field?

Comment: you could create a table with one column to store those values and run a query against that...maybe create an index too :-)

Comment: Can recreate your table in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What is the source of the list of values contained within your "IN?" Is it hard coded?  Are you sourcing it from a separate query?  Is it parameters being passed in?  How this data is made available may result in different options/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [Temporary Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) (see under Temporary Table), create a smart index on that temporary table, insert all the data into that temporary table, and then do an inner join between the temporary and the 'bi_bunrui_syouhin_shop_day_jyutyuu' table.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue. You can replace IN with Exists and Try this. But truly It is not an exact way of using Exists.

Ex:

Select * from Table1 where id exists (Select id from Table 2)

You can use this as a reference.

[Difference between EXISTS and IN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql)

Please let me know the result.

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM bi_bunrui_syouhin_shop_day_jyutyuu AS bi
WHERE bi.bunrui_code IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2)` --- You have to create a table Table 2 with all the numbers inserted into it.