# SQL where equal to expression

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I do like this

```
select * 
from tableA JOIN 
tableB ON tableA.id=tableB.id 
where tableB.someId = select id from otherTable where anotherId = 1
```

I have 2 where, possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `=` when the subquery returns only 1 value.

When subquery returns more than 1 value, you will have to use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

1. Using `IN`:

   ```
   select * 
   from tableA JOIN 
   tableB ON tableA.id=tableB.id 
   where tableB.someId IN (select id 
                       from otherTable 
                       where anotherId = 1)
   ```

   `IN` determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

   Read more [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).
2. USING `EXISTS`:

   ```
   select * 
   from tableA JOIN 
   tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id 
   where EXISTS (select id 
         from otherTable 
         where anotherId = 1
         and tableB.someId = otherTable .id)
   ```

Comment: You don't *have to use * `in`.  In fact, `exists` can have better performance.  `in` is a totally reasonable option though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`IN` Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
select * 
from tableA JOIN 
tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id 
where tableB.someId IN (select id 
                        from otherTable
                        where anotherId = 1)
```

You could also use the [`EXISTS` Condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
select * 
from tableA JOIN 
tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id 
where EXISTS (select id 
              from otherTable ot
              where anotherId = 1
              and tableB.someId = ot.id)
```

`=` would also work fine, if the subquery returned a single value.

[Difference between EXISTS and IN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24929/1492578)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tableA 
JOIN tableB ON tableA.id=tableB.id 
join otherTable ON tableb.id = othertable.id 
where otherTable.anotherId = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily do the same thing, because the id could be duplicated in `othertable`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff which would mean what ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: That means with n matching records in otherTable you get n times as many result rows. Only when only one record matches, then you get the same number of rows as you would with IN or EXISTS.