# please help me how update fron select in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
update employees set salary=salary*10/100+salary
where EmployeeID (select EmployeeID from employees where salary<2000)
```

Comment: 1. Don't use bold unless needed 2. What exactly is your problem? 3. MySQL and SQL Server are not the same thing. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: This update will effectively do NOTHING. 10/100 will result in 0 because of integer division. Then through the order of operations the net result will be that no value is actually changed. If the idea is to give everyone a 10% increase you could do the math a LOT simpler with salary * 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the IN

```
update employees set salary=salary*10/100+salary
where EmployeeID IN (select EmployeeID from employees where salary<2000)
```

As suggested by Lamak

```
update employees set salary=salary*10/100+salary
where salary<2000
```

Another option.

```
update employees e1 set salary=salary*10/100+salary
where EXISTS (select NULL 
              from employees e2 
              where e2.salary<2000 
                and e1.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
             )
```

The `EXISTS` is overkill in your case but may be very usefull.
[You should read about it. here's a good start :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql) .

In your case you should use  only the condition `salary<2000` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Or, you know, just use `WHERE salary < 2000`

Comment: See my comment above about integer math. As coded, this update will do nothing.