# Laravel5.1 query and subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How can I improve this query:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_thread WHERE
    thread_id not in (
        SELECT auth_id FROM forum_auth WHERE auth_group_id=1 and auth_type=2 and auth_visible=0
    )
    and thread_id in (
            SELECT thread_id FROM forum_thread WHERE
            category_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT auth_id FROM forum_auth WHERE auth_group_id=1 and auth_visible=0 and auth_type=1
            )
    )
ORDER BY last_post_id DESC limit 30
```

Thanks for answer

Comment: why do you want to change it?

Comment: This query is very complicated. I would like change it for something like that:
ForumThread::whereNotIn('thread_id', {auth_id_array})->whereIn('thread_id', {thread_id_array})->orderBy('last_post_id', 'DESC')->limit(30)->get(); but i have a problem to create subquery in subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query for **better performance:**

```
SELECT * FROM forum_thread WHERE
thread_id NOT EXIST(
    SELECT auth_id FROM forum_auth WHERE auth_group_id=1 and auth_type=2 and auth_visible=0
)
and thread_id EXIST(
        SELECT thread_id FROM forum_thread WHERE
        category_id NOT EXIST(
                SELECT auth_id FROM forum_auth WHERE auth_group_id=1 and auth_visible=0 and auth_type=1
        )
)
ORDER BY last_post_id DESC limit 30
```

Just change **NOT IN** to **NOT EXIST** - see this link:  [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

and also change **IN** to **EXIST** - see also this link: [Difference between EXISTS and IN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, i very helpful, but i still looking how change this query to laravel query builder