# sql subquery In function

Tags: mysql, sql-server

here still got lots to learn thanks for the help in advance. *bows
tried several time cant seems to get it to work hope to get some help from more experienced coders

I want to show staff that are **not teaching anyone**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy6Pa.png)
original table

```
Staff_ID    Mentor_ID   First_Name                Last_Name                
----------- ----------- ------------------------- -------------------------               
101         NULL        May                       Ou                     
102         101         Io                        Rush                   
103         102         Ley                       Have                     
104         103         Stephanie                 Soon                    
105         101         Iat                       Raiz                     
106         101         Rina                      shion
```

--notes

- not having a mentor id they are not learning from anyone
- having a mentor id learning that that person e,g  102 staff "Io Rush" 
  is learning from  staff 101 "May Ou" therefore means staff 101 is
  teaching 102 as well.
- therefore if staff id of a staff did not appear in mentor id they are
  not teaching anyone e.g. staff 104, 105 & 106

--basic key points

- staff 101 is not learning from any one but is teaching
  other people
- staff 102,103,104,105,106 are all learning from someone
- staff 101,102,103 are the only staff that are teaching other staff
- **staff 104,105,106 are the only ones not teaching anyone**

--my codings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM staff
WHERE Staff_ID  IN (SELECT Mentor_ID FROM staff)
```

--Result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqQ92.png)

```
Staff_ID    Mentor_ID   First_Name                Last_Name                
----------- ----------- ------------------------- -------------------------                   
101         NULL        May                       Ou                     
102         101         Io                        Rush                   
103         102         Ley                       Have
```

-- this show the complete opposite of what i am going for as this show all staff that **is teaching someone**

-- so i tought of an idea an since its the opposite should be just adding a NOT will give me what i one so i type the following code

--coding 2 :

```
SELECT * 
FROM staff
WHERE Staff_ID NOT IN (SELECT Mentor_ID FROM staff)
```

--result:
blank....

no idea what else i can do --" kinda stuck now, btw i am still a newbie to mysql so there may be i function of stuff that i dont know of please bear with me*bows 
yup so that is a detailed description of my problem, i thank all those in advance for taking your time to read my problem all advice is appreciated, hope to hear from you guys soon *waves waves :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM staff s WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM staff m WHERE m.Mentor_ID=s.Staff_ID )
```

Your last query was in a way similar, but you fell into a common pitfall with the `NOT IN` construct. It works fine as long as there are no `null` values in your list you are comparing against. But unfortunately there *is* a `null` value. The above form with `EXISTS` will always work.

I changed your data for a little [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3453c/1) (using `0` instead of `null`) and you can see that both versions work there.

Comment: thank you so much for you help AH ha! i knew it there is a function i didnt know will do more research on the not exists functions u use thanks again for ur help *wave waves ;P

Answer (score 0):

*EXISTS* is much faster than IN when the subquery results is very large.
*IN* is faster than EXISTS when the subquery results is very small.

This will help you [Difference between EXISTS and IN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql)