# c# mysql insert query, if record exists then update

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, insert-query

I am trying to insert the new records in table, I have two columns

```
      user_records
 ------------------------
| Attribute |  Datatype  |
|------------------------|
| user_id   | varchar(25)|
| count     | int        |
 ------------------------
```

Query :

```
INSERT into user_records Values("nix_1", 0)
```

but if the user already exists, then it should increase count by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax?

```
INSERT INTO user_records (user_id, count) VALUES ('nix_1', 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I tried `INSERT INTO user_records VALUES('nix_1', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count+1` but it gives error `Unrecognized keyword (near ON)`, `Unrecognized keyword (near DUPLICATE)`, `Unrecognized keyword (Near Key)`.

Comment: Which version of MySQL and which data engine?

Comment: I am using xampp with sql version `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev` and XAMPP `Version 3.22`

Answer (score 0):

You would have check if the record exists before attempting to `INSERT`. Your query should be something in line with below. Example works in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @sUserID VARCHAR(25) = "nix_1";    // This should be the parameter passed on into the stored procedure

IF EXISTS(SELECT user_id FROM WHERE user_id = @sUserID)
    // Increase the count
    UPDATE user_records SET count = count  + 1 
        WHERE user_id = @sUserID
ELSE
    // Insert new record
    INSERT INTO user_records Values (@sUserID , 0)
```

Please refer to the below links for info on `EXIST`

[EXISTS (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188336.aspx)

[SQL EXISTS Operator](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php)

[Difference between EXISTS and IN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964770/718373)