# Optimize a query with MySQL in repeated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that checks if two columns of a table are `in` another
The query works, I hope you can optimize the call in because they are equal. I doubt if there is a performance penalty because two calls are made to the same query

```
SELECT name,lastname FROM TABLA_A
WHERE 
name IN (
  SELECT name FROM TABLE_B
)
OR
lastname IN (
  SELECT lastname FROM TABLE_B
)
```

ANOTHER WAY

```
SELECT a.name,a.lastname
FROM TABLE_A as a
join TABLE_B  as b on a.name=b.name
or a.lastname= b.lastname
```

> try to join, is a valid option? there are other ways to make this task
>   more efficient? thank you very much

Comment: Please synchronize two queries. It is hard to understand the columns from two query. If they return same result edit them with same column name.

Comment: Indeed INNER JOIN is the best and simplest option.

Comment: You can use `EXISTS`

Comment: I replaced the incorrect `sql-server` tag with `mysql` because of the question's title

Comment: Keep in mind that would like to know your options and compare performance (use Sql Sever)

Comment: First query returns not duplicate rows, second may (depending on data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a performance issue in using `OR` that you can use `UNION` instead like this:

```
SELECT name, lastname 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE name IN (
  SELECT name 
  FROM TABLE_B)
UNION -- If there is not any duplicate use `UNION ALL` instead
SELECT name, lastname 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE lastname IN (
  SELECT lastname 
  FROM TABLE_B);
```

**[[`SQL Fiddle Demo`]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f24580/1)**

Comment: this would make return duplicate records if both the value and `a.lastname` `a.name`  are in the TABLE_B?

Comment: Using `UNION` will remove duplicates !?

Comment: It is possible with this solution proposed to eliminate duplicate records returned?

Comment: How those records should eliminate? and if you have another question ask another question ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXISTS which works more efficiently than IN from every aspects:

```
SELECT a.name,
    a.lastname
FROM TABLE_A as a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.name 
             FROM TABLE_B b WHERE a.name = b.name OR a.lastname= b.lastname)
```

Comment: [There is no difference between using `EXISTS` vs `IN` as a performance issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3964770/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 0):

As you have already done

```
SELECT a.name, a.lastname
FROM TABLE_A as a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B as b on a.name=b.name OR a.lastname= b.lastname
```

Comment: is the method I made, any other suggestions?