# What is better option? IN operator or EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, operators

What is better option? Using IN operator or EXISTS operator? In term of performance and server load. Is there any supporting factors for IN and/or EXISTS operator in database (like index, constraint or something)?

Here is sample queries using IN and EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customer_ID IN (SELECT Cust_ID FROM Sales);
```

AND

```
SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customers WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Cust_ID FROM Sales);
```

If the two queries were different, what is better way to count or list Customer? Or if query is more complex in like below.

```
SELECT sub_id FROM subscription 
WHERE start_date = CURDATE()
AND end_date > CURDATE()
AND sub_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sub_id FROM subscription 
WHERE start_date < CURDATE());
```

Is it possible to replace NOT IN operator with NOT EXISTS? In this case, rewriting above query with NOT EXISTS is better or something?

Comment: Perhaps a JOIN?

Comment: both are not same.. Do you mean `..Customers c WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM Sales s where s.Cust_ID= c.Customer_ID);`

Comment: This is can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two queries do different things.  You probably intend a correlated subquery for `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Customer_ID c
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Sales s WHERE s.Cust_ID = c.Customer_Id);
```

Both methods are fine for expressing your logic.  I tend to prefer `EXISTS` for two reasons:

- `NOT EXISTS` is generally a better choice than `NOT IN` because of the way it handles `NULL`.  This does not apply to `EXISTS`/`IN`, but it spills over.
- `EXISTS` is generally no worse than `IN` from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You could use them for the same, but `exists` keyword is generaly used when you are checking if conditional statements.

`In` keyword, is generaly used with a list comparation.

Also, as jarlh says, you can replace `in` using `join`.