# Why SQL "NOT IN" is so slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my SQL code:

```
select count(1) 
from customers 
where id in(
    select custid
    from accounts
    where sid in(72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79)
) 
and id not in(
    select custid 
    from accounts 
    where sid in(80,81)
);
```

Tables are indexed properly. Can this code be rewritten for better performance?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please (make sure you preserve the indention), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The `NOT IN` criteria can be removed without changing the result. Pls review your question.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez - the way I read it, a given id could have multiple rows in the accounts table. If an id in that table has both a case where sid = 72 and sid = 80, then it shouldn't be counted, hence the need for the NOT IN

Comment: @kbball Got it. Interesting, and good you clarified it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try EXISTS:

```
select count(1) 
from customers c
where exists (
    select 1
    from accounts a
    where sid in(72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79)
    and a.custid = c.custid
) 
and not exists (
    select 1
    from accounts a
    where sid in(80,81)
    and a.custid = c.custid
);
```

This might be helpful read: [Difference between EXISTS and IN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql)

Comment: WOW! I've got the result in a second instead of 5 minute!

Answer (score 0):

Join your tables rather than using 2 subquerys.

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN accounts a ON c.id = a.sid
WHERE id IN (72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79)
```

Comment: The count would be too high, because you would potentially be counting ids that have a row in accounts where sid in (80, 81)

Comment: That won't give the right result if Customers have several Accounts

Answer (score 0):

A minus query might be more efficient. Something like this:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM 
(
SELECT c.id 
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN accounts a ON c.id = a.sid
WHERE id IN (72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79)
MINUS
SELECT c.id 
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN accounts a ON c.id = a.sid
WHERE id IN (80,81)
)
```

Comment: I have tried this but got a syntax error - near MINUS.