# Why adding where cause with NOT IN to a SQL slow in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written a SQL query that seems very simple, tableA with primary key x, and ytime is a timestamp field.

```
select a.x, b.z from 
    # tableA join tableB etc.
where a.id not in (select x from tableA where a.ytime is not null)
```

There is another stackflow similar to this one but that one only talks about smaller subset of data.

[Why SQL "NOT IN" is so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239891/why-sql-not-in-is-so-slow)

Not sure if I need to index ytime column.

Comment: Please post `explain (analyze, buffers)`. Also, when you use subquery for your `IN` condition then postgres actually joins those tables instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no science to back this up -- only antecdotal history, but for cases where the "in" list is significantly large, I have found that the semi-join (or anti-join in this case) is typically much more efficient than the in list:

```
select a1.x, b.z
from 
  tableA a1
  join tableB b on ...
where not exists (
  select null
  from tablea a2
  where a1.id = a2.x and a2.ytime is not null
)
```

When I say significant, a query than ran for minutes using the in-list ran in just seconds after I changed it to the semi.

Try it and see if it makes a difference.

I made some assumptions since your code was largely notional, but I think you get the idea.