# Sql server not parsing Sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query in SQL server 2012 which is running fine when the whole query is run, but the inner query is not running individually because AdviceRecordID doesn't belong to tblB.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubLOBID 
FROM tblA 
WHERE AdviceRecordID 
IN (SELECT AdviceRecordID
    FROM tblB
)
```

The first case, where the whole query is run, is not considering the WHERE condition at all and returing all the results without any error which is strange for me.

Comment: Because sub-query had column name which belongs to outer-query table therefore when we run query as a whole then SQL engine uses outer table column and had no problem to run that.

Comment: Provide alias names to each table and then use alias name with column names to understand it better.

Comment: The subquery as written is useless and the query can be simplified to `select distinct sublobid from tbla where advicerecord is not null`

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name : both the tables are different. Please check it carefully.

Comment: Thanks BhatiaAshish. I was assuming SQL server would parse each query before running.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing out NULL case.

Comment: @AjayAgrawal: I am aware of that.

Comment: Is there any good article on this which explains this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected and required by the SQL standard. If a subquery references a column that is not available in the tables of the subquery, but is a valid column in the outer query, the value from the outer query's column is used.

So the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubLOBID 
FROM tblA 
WHERE AdviceRecordID IN (SELECT AdviceRecordID
                         FROM tblB);
```

Is in fact a **co**-related subquery and is parsed and executed as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubLOBID 
FROM tblA 
WHERE AdviceRecordID IN (SELECT tblA.AdviceRecordID
                         FROM tblB);
```

So for each row in `tblA` the subquery returns the value of `tblA.AdviceRecordID` once for each row in `tblB` and compares that to the rules of the `IN` operator.

That's why the query as a whole is valid, and behaves like no where clause was used as the above is equivalent to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubLOBID 
FROM tblA 
WHERE AdviceRecordID IS NOT NULL;
```

And if there are no NULL values in the column AdviceRecordID then the `WHERE` clause is not filtering out anything.

Comment: So the trick is, SQL server doesn't parse each inner query individaully. It depends on the outer query as well.

Comment: @AjayAgrawal: a SQL query is always parsed as **one** (complete) statement.

Comment: I changed the column name in inner query and replaced with a column name which is not present in either of the tables. It is not parsing and throwig error. So your analysis is correct

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` clause.

Check the difference:

[Difference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql)

[Difference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065329/sql-server-in-vs-exists-performance)

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.SubLOBID 
FROM tblA A
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT B.AdviceRecordID
    FROM tblB B
    WHERE B.AdviceRecordID=A.AdviceRecordID
)
```

Comment: From the question: "*because AdviceRecordID doesn't belong to tblB*" so `SELECT B.AdviceRecordID` is invalid

Comment: In that case no need any subquery

Comment: I prefer in because it's less code. I would only use exists if there were actually a performance issue personally.

Comment: @SandipPatel: here the question is, why SQL server doesn't throw any error in the query mentioned.

Comment: @SandipPatel I disagree. In() and Exists() for logically equivalent queries produce more than often same query plan - and better is to use query syntax, corresponding more closely to problem description and therefore easier to understand and maintain. It was many years ago, when SQL optimizers didn't handle these cases similarly - nowadays I haven't seen differences in query plans.

Comment: Try with sub query which return `NULL` , you may got difference between both