# What is the performance difference of using an = vs IN operator with EXISTS criteria?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server, when using the WHERE EXISTS criteria, is there any performance difference of using an = vs an IN operator?

Example:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    last_name
FROM
    sales.customers c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sales.orders o
        WHERE customer_id = c.customer_id --we can also replace = with IN - for example customer_id IN c.customer_id or say c.customer_id IN customer_id
    )
```

Another example would be:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    last_name
FROM
    sales.customers c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #Customers x --say #Customers is temp table containing a couple of customers for which we want to show the output
        WHERE c.customer_id = x.customer_id --we can also replace = with IN - for example c.customer_id IN x.customer_id or say x.customer_id IN c.customer_id
    )
```

This question is marked as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql). That question is re. EXISTS vs IN. Whereas my question is re = vs IN when using EXISTS

Comment: There is already a good thread on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql

Comment: Are you serious? Did you even read my question. I am not asking for difference between EXIST vs IN clause. I am asking for the difference between using = vs IN in an EXISTS clause!

Comment: Did you try comparing execution plans? Both *should* be the same because your `IN` will only include the same column reference as your `=` and the `IN` is just a syntactic sugar for a bunch of `=` with `OR`s.

Comment: Yes I think they are logically the same, but check the execution plan to be sure

Comment: @EzLo - but Im not using an OR!

Comment: `Column IN (1, 2)` is the same as `Column = 1 OR Column = 2`. So if you only have 1 value in the `IN`...

Comment: In my query, there is no OR; If I have 1 values then you are right; what if multiple values

Comment: @variable if you have multiple values then you can't compare `=` against an `IN` unless you add `AND`s or `OR`s with the `=`. If you mean multiple values as in a column reference, a correlated subquery (which is this case) will execute once for each row of the outer set, `customer_id` will only hold 1 value "at a time".

Comment: Agree with your last point - will hold 1 value at a time. One side of the = will hold one value. Where as the other side holds multiple values. Exists evaluates each row (one row at a time) from source table with multiple rows from the target table. So then is there any performance consideration when using = vs IN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how the correlated subquery works together with `EXISTS`.

An equal comparison (`=`) evaluates **a particular value** against **another particular value** and returns true or false. It can't evaluate multiple values, unless you add additional logical operators `AND` / `OR`. The `IN` operator is just a way to simplify a bunch of `OR` with `=` operators so it's easier to read as Zohar explained in another answer.

In the other hand, the `EXISTS` operator uses an ***left semi join*** to check for the existence of a particular record. `EXISTS` is used in boolean contexts whenever you want to check if a particular row exists or not. The SQL engine stops searching for matching rows *as soon as it finds the first one*. This is the ***left semi join***'s purpose and one of the differences with ***left outer join*** (other than retrieving the joining table's data and matching rows amounts).

So when you write:

```
FROM
    sales.customers c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sales.orders o
        WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    )
```

You are using a correlated sub-query linking `customers` with `orders`. The subquery is used in the context of an `EXISTS` operator, this will make the engine search, for each row of `sales.customers`, if there is *at least* 1 row in `sales.orders` that satisfies this condition:

```
WHERE o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

This condition will result as `false` on each order that's not from the customer we are currently checking. The engine will ignore these rows because we are looking for existence. Only the rows from `customers` which have a `customer_id` that produces a row in the subquery will be returned.

If we change the condition to an `IN`:

```
FROM
    sales.customers c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sales.orders o
        WHERE o.customer_id IN (c.customer_id)
    )
```

The subquery will check for existence on table `sales.orders` that satisfies the condition:

```
WHERE o.customer_id IN (c.customer_id)
```

This happens to be the same `c.customer_id` that we referenced in the `=` example. The behaviour for the engine will be the same as the previous example; check if there is at least 1 row on `orders` that match the `customer_id` from `customers`.

Hence, both `=` and `IN` will work the same way.

Comment: This is a good explanation on how the `exists` operator works, but it's irrelevant to how the `in` operator works - and the fact is, that when ever an `in` operator has only one value in the list, it's exactly the same as using the `=` operator.

Answer (score 2):

No difference whatsoever.

When you are writing

```
WHERE A IN(B)
```

It's exactly the same as writing

```
WHERE A = B
```

If either `A` or `B` is a column, expression or a constant doesn't change the nature of the `IN` operator.

If you where to write

```
WHERE A IN(B, C)
```

It would be the same as writing

```
WHERE A = B OR A = C
```

The fact that this condition is a part of a subquery inside an `EXISTS` operator is irrelevant.

Comment: Your example is a = 1; how about when we have multiple values. Then = is not equivalent to IN. Unless there are OR's along with the =

Comment: Yes, that's correct - but `where a in(b)` is the exact condition you have. it doesn't matter of `b` is a constant or a column name.

Comment: My original answer had the correct conclusion but for the wrong reasons, and only after I've read your comment I've realized it - hence the intensive edit.