# Difference between "exists", and "in" in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

This is my query

```
select nom, prenom, mail ,trig 
from dbo.reseau
where  nom, prenom, mail, trig in  
(
    select mail, nom, prenom, mail, trig
    from dbo.reseau
    group by mail, nom, prenom, mail, trig
    having count(1) > 1
)
```

This query don't work they tell me that I have to use exists. I used id, and it doesn't work.

Comment: What's your question here? _"this query don't work"_ isn't a question. Are you asking about [the difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql) which makes your Q a dup, or how to solve something else?

Comment: You need to explain more about what you are trying to achieve and show some sample data plus expected results. For a start `IN` only works with a single column, not a list of columns.

Comment: to solve the probleme of my query. Can i have a result with this query ?

Comment: i want display duplicates for each colomn

Comment: 1) [edit] any improvements into your question. 2) **Show some sample data**, because duplicates for each column isn't clear in itself. Do you want to show rows where any column is a duplicate? Or all columns are a duplicate?

Comment: i want to show rows where any column is a duplicate

Comment: Sorry, closing it with my vote. I suggest you sit down and spend a day formulating a query that is specific. And in the meantime, instead of "they keep telling me" you also sit down and read documentation - the syntax and examples in teh documentation that clearly explain what "in" and "exists" ae for will help. I am not sure where you got the idea that "in" could be used when TSQL clearly states: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - "Is a subquery that has a result set of one column". Yours has 5.

Comment: And to add to TomToms comment, you've got a history of poor quality questions, I suggest reading through the FAQ again on how to ask a good question e.g. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). We all want to help you, but we are all strangers to your system/design/requirements, so you have to make the effort to communicate to us your question in a clear, concise manner. And a [mre] is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXISTS**: Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

In other words... Does this subquery return any rows?

**IN**: Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

In other words... Hey, get me the the first and last name of employees whose Job Title is 'Design Engineer', 'Tool Designer', 'Marketing Assistant'
code snippet from link below.

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.JobTitle  
FROM Person.Person AS p  
JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e  
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID  
WHERE e.JobTitle IN ('Design Engineer', 'Tool Designer', 'Marketing Assistant');  
GO
```

**Further reading**

[MS DOCS EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[MS DOCS IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not valid. You seem to be looking for tuple equality:

```
where (nom, prenom, mail, trig) in (
    select mail, nom, mail, trig
    from ...
)
```

Few databases support this syntax, and SQL Server is not one of them.

It seems like you want to exhibit duplicates. You could use exists, but you would need a primary key column (or set of columns), and it is not obvious which one it would be from looking at the query. Assuming `id`:

```
select r.*
from dbo.reseau r
where exists (
    select 1 
    from dbo.reseau r1
    where 
        r1.id <> r.id 
        and r1.nom = r.nom 
        and r1.prenom = r.prenom 
        and r1.mail = r.mail 
        and r1.trig = r.trig
)
```

I think this would be simpler expressed with a window count:

```
select *
from (
    select r.*, count(*) over(partition by nom, prenom, mail, trig) cnt
    from dbo.reseau r
) r
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: this query is used to display duplicates for this colomn